# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies || Precise Location issue

Tags: android, google-play-console, policy

i'm having some problem on sending my app to production in play store

See, the first time i tried to send my app to production i received an email 3 days later with this:

After this I read articles and play console policies , and then i changed in my app. Use only course location , remove Fine location , also from manifest file.

> In Console
> remove tick from precise location and then send change in review .

> after review same issue getting in email .
> I didn't understand what is the actual issue.

[image: play console image issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Data type section

[image]

> Data usage handling

[image]

[image]

this resolve my issue, hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most properly this is how you should answer the data safety form:

Precise location:

- Collected?    Yes
- Shared? No
- Processed ephemerally? No (or yes if you do not know who is the user when you process the location
- Required? Yes
- Purposes? App functionality